# React-top-loading-bar on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I tried implementing this https://github.com/klendi/react-top-loading-bar to my projet. So far the buttons are working to display the state of the bar, but I don't know how to "link" the state of the progress bar when my pages on load.

My code (App.js):

```
import Home from './pages/home';
import Menu from './components/menu';
import Clients from './pages/clients';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import LoadingBar from 'react-top-loading-bar';

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0)
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>

          <Menu/>

          <LoadingBar height="3px"  color="#1BC5BD" progress={progress} onLoaderFinished={() => setProgress(0)} />
          <button
            onClick={() => setProgress(progress + 10)}
          >
            Add 10%
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => setProgress(progress + 20)}
          >
            Add 20%
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => setProgress(100)}
          >
            Complete
          </button>
          <br/>

          <Switch>
             <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
             <Route path='/clients' component={Client} />
             
          </Switch>
          
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Edit : I tried `<div onClick={() => setProgress(100)}> <Menu /></div>` and it's actually loading with the new pages but only one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the progress each time you start to load something new.

Better use the continuousStart when you start to load something and then set it to complete as soon loading finishes:

```
<button
     onClick={() => ref.current.continuousStart()} >
```

as soon loading finishes

```
() => ref.current.complete()
```

Here I made a codesandbox for you with an example.
Put some more of your code in there if you need more help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-haze-iye6s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes I saw that in the example, but how to link this to my pages. Like the pages I have in <Menu /> ?

Comment: Thank you. This is close to what I wanted to achieve. The problem is that I have the component Menu that have a lot of link inside. When I press on the menu, the loading occurs just the first time. It's like the whole menu is one button.

Comment: Show me the code of Menu, and I will take a look at it.

Comment: The JS section of https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/bGBRawL
Links are in {Navlink}.

Comment: could you provide a functional example please, you could clone my codesandbox for that. I have already added the code from your menu there, but I don't have the time to make it work right now.

Comment: Yes. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-loading-forked-d8i41?file=/src/Menu.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-loading-forked-cj9pc?file=/src/App.js
Here you go

Comment: Thank you very much ! Can you explain to me what you did cuz I'm still noobish haha.

Comment: I just bound the handler for starting the loading bar to the menu buttons. As soon as you click them, the navbar gets started and the URL changes. Check the `App`and `Menu` component for details.  Then I set up the react-router, so that the `Dashboard` and `Clients` components are loaded depending on the URL.  As soon as one of the components is mounted, the loading bar is set to complete in componentDidMount of the components. That's it.

Comment: You are welcome. Take your time, play around with the example, and try to reproduce it yourself. That will help you understand it even better. ;)

Comment: Hey there one who stuck in react top progress bar, plz refer to @henk solution, he mentioned codesandbox which might helpful for someone. I was hitting my head for top progress bar finally ended with henk's solution. Thanks a lot Henk.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are seeking this answer. If you want to do something after page is loaded, you could do it in the useEffect hooks. Like this:

```
// Use cumputedProgress as a dependency
useEffect(() => setProgress(computedProgress), 
  [computedProgress]);
```

If you mean the progress doesn't work here, then have a try to use Ref to handle this loading bar.

Comment: I'm still newbie in React so I really don't have any clue in it. I just want to display the progressbar when I load a page that's it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a lib like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanem/react-nprogress to get the page progression, or if you want a complete solution and you're using Next.js you can try this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-toploader